# Rails 4 - Making a Sum on a property of related ojects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have the following models:

```
class Bill < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :transactions
end

class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :amount, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }

    belongs_to :bill
    belongs_to :product
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :name , presence: true, length: { in: 3..20 }

    has_many :transactions, as: :sellable
end
```

Basically every bill has many transactions, selling different quantities of different products.

Given a group of bills, for instance `Bill.all` (but it could be any other subset), **how could I get a relationship all how many units have been sold of every product?**

Something like...

```
@sales = {
    product: {id: 1, name: "cream"} , amount: 2,
    product: {id: 1, name: "pencil"}, amount: 23,
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need to reference Bill at all, everything you need is in your transaction model, you should be able to do:

```
Transaction.group(:product_id).sum(:amount)
```

This should give you something like:

```
{12: 345, 13: 400, 14: 720}
```

Where the keys are the product_ids and the values are the sum of the amounts

If you have a subset of bills that you'd like to query, you can use a subquery:

```
Transaction.where(bill_id: Bill.any_ar_query.pluck(:id)).group(:product_id).sum(:amount)
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I did not explain myself properly. This solution works for all bills, but if I wanted a certain subset of bills, this wouldnt work (for instance, `Bill.belonging(customer: "Johnny")` ). I updated the question.

Comment: That's much more difficult. I thin I'd go down the route of `Transaction.where(bill_id: Bill.whatever_grouping.pluck(:id)).group(:product).sum(:amount)`

Comment: Genius! That worked, except that I had to change `:product` for `:product id`. You should add it to the main answer! :) Thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class method and apply it in whatever `ActiveRecord::Relation` you have. Like this:

```
 def self.sum_by_product
   joins(:product).group(:product_id).sum(:amount)     
 end
```

Then you use it in this way:

```
Bill.where(status: 'paid').sum_by_product
```

Hope this help

Comment: I get `undefined method 'transactions' for #<Class:0x007f2eea6f6088>`. Remember that transactions is a property of the object, not of the class.

Comment: If you read my question, I said `a subset of bills`, not just one.